# CakePHP/Chrome - something with the Facebook plugin is causing my site to auto refresh over and over and over

Tags: php, cakephp, google-chrome, facebook

Something with "echo $facebook->init();" is causing my site to refresh over and over again in Chrome only.  (Edit*:  This also happens on my Android phone w/ Dolphin Browser.)

The code that calls this is:

```
echo $facebook-init();
```

and it generates this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[

          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId   : '203899102970207',
              session : null, // don't refetch the session when PHP already has it
              status  : true, // check login status
              cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
            });
            // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
              window.location.reload();
            });
          };
          (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
          }());

//]]>
</script>
```

Obviously I assume it's the window.location.reload() that's doing it, but - that's not code I added or can edit manually.

Has anyone seen this or have any idea what could be causing it / how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance for any help / direction.

Comment: what code do u have? lol

Comment: My crystal ball is broken today

Comment: The point is, I don't even know what code to look at or show you - This is the first time I've ever seen this, and it's also my first CakePHP site, so - I assumed maybe it was some kind of CakePHP issue that someone's come across before.

Comment: How about your cakephp code? At least, the relevant bits. Show us anything you think would be useful so that we can help you as best as we can.

Comment: @Cyclone - how can I give you the "relevant" bits when I have no clue what the problem is.  How can I know what's relevant?

Comment: @Dave any code you have for redirection, any HTML output that could cause a refresh...

Comment: @Cyclone - I've added some details in my question - those were the 3 things I could think of - htaccess, meta redirect, and then I found that facebook line that looks suspicious.

Comment: @Dave Well that code causes the page to reload if that particular event is triggered, is something causing that event to trigger automatically?

Comment: @Cyclone - not that I'm aware of.  It seems if it were - it seems if I were triggering it, it would refresh regardless of the browser, y/n?  I checked, and I am logged into facebook in both Firefox4 and Chrome - not sure if maybe being logged in triggers it?

Comment: @Dave Try logging out and visiting the page in chrome. If it doesnt refresh then there's your issue. Perhaps some aspect of the code is only triggering in Chrome because of its javascript interpreter.

Comment: what exactly is $facebook->init(); A cake function? Custom? plugin?

Comment: It's for the [CakePHP Facebook plugin](http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/229/CakePHP_Facebook_Plugin_Auth_Facebook_and_more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [lastest version of the CakePHP Facebook plugin](http://www.webtechnick.com/wtn/blogs/view/238/Facebook_Plugin_v2_0_Graph_System), it allows you to pass `false` to the init() call which keeps it from refreshing over and over (or even once).

This doesn't seem like the best solution, because when a facebook user comes to the page, they won't know they're logged in until the next pageview, but - seems to be the only solution for now.

```
$this->facebook->init(null, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes the .htaccess file can cause this. Check that first. Eliminates the possibility at least

Comment: I've added my htaccess file contents to the question - I don't really understand those yet, so - hard for me to tell if anything stands out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the issue lies with the cookies. In your "configuration", do you use cookie => true?

Have a look here: http://saizai.livejournal.com/897522.html Allthough it's for Safari, it could work for Chrome as well. Try clearing all of your cookies in Chrome, and to set the use of cookie in your facebook app on false. I hope it helps a bit!

Comment: Don't suppose you have any examples for CakePHP instead of Rails?  I'm looking, and will try this if I find anything.

Comment: no luck.  Turned off cookies in FB.init and cleared my cookies - same issue.  I do not specifically set cookies to true... don't think I need to though